# Put user_timeline Twitter on a website with new API 1.1

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Time ago I have this code to put the 3 last tweets of an user:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/"+ user +".json?callback=?&count=3", function(data) {
    jQuery.each(data, function(i, object) {
        var textt = object.text.linkify().atify().hashify();
        jQuery("#twitter").append('<p><span class="text">' + textt + '</span><br/><span class="quan">' +parseTwitterDate(object.created_at) + '</span></p><hr/>');
    });     
});
```

Now, I read that API have changed for a new URL and needs to create an App with secure token (Oauth) for let to see tweets on a site.

I've created the App with the user that I would like to shown the tweets and I have the secure keys, but How I can show now the tweets? I need to put this keys on some line of Javascript code? But with Javascript I can't put this keys because are secrets...

Answer (score 3):

In short: you need a OAuth authentication before you can use the 1.1 API. The only way is to implement this step server side and pull the feed from there with Javascript. While doing this caching the feed increases page load.

Remember to check out the display REQUIREMENTS from twitter. Really, yes really!

I've been working on a solution. In my search I found the following resources very helpful:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-async-documentation.html